# how to highlight menu item on selection?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have four menu items and I want them to be highlighted on selection. I tried to use
`item.setIcon()`, it works fine but when I select other menu item, the previous one is also highlighted. Is there any possibility of making only current selection highlighted?

This is my menu.xml

```
<item 
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Home"
    android:icon="@drawable/home72"/>
<item 
    android:id="@+id/location"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Locations"
    android:icon="@drawable/locations72"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/preQualify"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Pre-Qualify"
    android:icon="@drawable/prequalify72"/>
<item 
    android:id="@+id/products"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Products"
    android:icon="@drawable/products72"/>
```

This is my java file:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId()){

    case R.id.home:
        //item.setIcon(icon);
        final ProgressDialog homeDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        homeDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        homeDialog.setCancelable(false);

        storeLocator = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.storeLocator);
        storeLocator.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        storeLocator.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //storeLocator.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        storeLocator.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                homeDialog.show();
                homeDialog.setProgress(0);
                activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);

                homeDialog.incrementProgressBy(progress);

                if(progress == 100 && homeDialog.isShowing())
                    homeDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        storeLocator.loadUrl("xxxx");
        //item.setIcon(R.drawable.homew);
        /*Toast.makeText(this, "Home selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show();*/
        break;

    case R.id.location:
        final ProgressDialog locationDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        locationDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        locationDialog.setCancelable(false);

        storeLocator = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.storeLocator);
        storeLocator.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        storeLocator.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //storeLocator.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        storeLocator.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                locationDialog.show();
                locationDialog.setProgress(0);
                activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);

                locationDialog.incrementProgressBy(progress);

                if(progress == 100 && locationDialog.isShowing())
                    locationDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        storeLocator.loadUrl("xxxx");

        //item.setIcon(R.drawable.lcoationw);
        /*Toast.makeText(this, "Location selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show();*/
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any possibility of making only current selection highlighted?

Keep track of what you have highlighted. When you highlight one, remove the highlight from the previous one.

Comment: how do I keep track of selection? I'm unable to figure it out!!

Comment: @AnilM: Store the last-highlighted `MenuItem` in a data member of your activity.