# How to highlight the custom menu item onFocus state in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu, android-tv, android-optionsmenu

[how to highlight menu item on selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708382/how-to-highlight-menu-item-on-selection)

I bumped into this which is quite near to my implementation. However, in my case the difference. As I am developing for TV and have controls like LEFT/RIGHT?CENTER etc. So I use a LocalBroadcastManager to receive a keyEvent from a custom layout class in my activity.

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        KeyEvent keyEvent = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.KEY_PRESSED_EVENT);
        Log.d(TAG, "Receiver got ketEventCode : " + keyEvent.getKeyCode());
        switch (keyEvent.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
                if (!PipLayout.isMenuOpened)
                    openOptionsMenu();
                else
                    closeOptionsMenu();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                return true;
       }
}
```

When I have say press LEFT key on my remote I do the following

```
menu.getItem(menuItemPosition).getActionView().requestFocus();
```

And yes focusable and focusableOnTouchMode is set to true but the item on which my cursor is is not highlighted in the UI although I have logs which show the update in the position of the menu item.

How can I highlight the menuItem that its pointing to ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/navigation.html#focus-selection) which discussed about implementation of highlights for focused and selected controls using [Drawable State List Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) which was provided by Android.

Try using `android:state_activated`.

> Boolean. "true" if this item should be used when the object is activated as the persistent selection (such as to "highlight" the previously selected list item in a persistent navigation view); "false" if it should be used when the object is not activated.

Comment: @Teyram Thanks for sharing this. But I opted to implement a custom menu as it was much more feasible in my case but I hope others benefit from this.